# Rendering photos taken in-app in a gallery view grid

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app where when there is no user-generated content, it is displaying a message, but when a user takes a photo, it displays the photo in a grid gallery view.

I am already using conditional logic in order to do this, however, when I press the camera button, the camera shows up and takes a photo, however that photo does not flow back to the home page in the desired format.

There is a screenshot below regarding the flow I am trying to achieve for your reference. Hoping someone can help rectify.

I have the full reproductive code below that can reproduce what is occurring. Based on what I have, my research and knowledge, this should be achieved already as I am pushing photos taken back to the homepage_1 through the following in the Camera page

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Homepage_1(
                  imgPath: path,
                )),
```

Here is the camera page reproductive code

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'preview_screen.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  var image; //
  List imageArray = []; //

  _openGallery() async {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    imageArray.add(image);
    setState(() {
      imageArray;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIndex = 0;
        });
        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIndex]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print('No camera available');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error :${err.code}Error message : ${err.message}');
    });
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _cameraToggleRowWidget(),
                      _cameraControlWidget(context),
                      Spacer()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display Camera preview.
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures
  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                _openGallery();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraToggleRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
          icon: Icon(
            _getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection),
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 24,
          ),
          label: Text(
            '${lensDirection.toString().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase()}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera_solid;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error:${e.code}\nError message : ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);
  }

  void _onCapturePressed(context) async {
    try {
      final path =
          join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path, '${DateTime.now()}.png');
      await controller.takePicture();

      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Homepage_1(
                  imgPath: path,
                )),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
  }

  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIndex =
        selectedCameraIndex < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIndex + 1 : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }
}
```

Here is the Homepage_1 code itself that contains the conditional logic

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    
    
    class Homepage_1 extends StatefulWidget {

  //specify a FINAL variable
  final imgPath;

  //this is the constructor which allows you to send it
  const Homepage_1({this.imgPath});

      @override
      _Homepage_1State createState() => _Homepage_1State();
    }
    
    class _Homepage_1State extends State<Homepage_1> {
      var image;
      List imageArray = [];
    
        _openGallery() async {
        image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
        imageArray.add(image);
        setState(() {
          imageArray;
        });
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print(imageArray);
        return Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
              Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 40, right: 0, bottom: 0),
                child:
                    Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                  Text(
                    'Title',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 60,
                      fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      margin:
                          EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 70, bottom: 0),
                      child: imageArray.isEmpty
                          ? Column(children: [
                              Text(
                                'Yikes! You have no photos',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 19,
                                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Click the circular button below.',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ])
                          : GridView.count(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              children: List.generate(imageArray.length, (index) {
                                var img = imageArray[index];
                                return Container(child: Image.file(this.widget.imgPath));
                              })))
                ]),
              )
            ]));
      }
    }
```

Here is also my bottom navigation for your reference

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Camera.dart';
import 'Homepage_1.dart';
import 'Settings.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
// properties

  int currentTab = 0;
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    Settings(),
    Camera(),
    Homepage_1(),
  ];

  Widget currentScreen = Homepage_1();

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        child: currentScreen,
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 80, height: 80),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong, size: 39),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Camera()));
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: CircleBorder(), primary: Color(0xff33333D)),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
        height: 60,
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 150,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        currentScreen = Homepage_1();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/Home_Selected.png"),
                          color: currentTab == 0
                              ? Color(0xff33333D)
                              : Color(0xffC6CBD1),
                        ),
                      ]),
                )
              ]),
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                MaterialButton(
                  minWidth: 150,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(
                      () {
                        currentScreen = Settings();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ImageIcon(
                          AssetImage("assets/Settings.png"),
                          color: currentTab == 1
                              ? Color(0xff33333D)
                              : Color(0xffC6CBD1),
                        ),
                      ]),
                )
              ])
            ]),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion try to keep right naming convention.   It is confusing from where you want to send the image ,and where it should display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your files. please look into it. Though you can directly use ImagePicker.pickImage in your home page but i solved it as per your code.
I used callback function to get the image from "camera.dart" into you homepage. For more understanding about callback functions you can refer the link [here](https://shriya-apps.medium.com/how-to-pass-parameter-in-callback-function-in-flutter-3e567c6805a4)

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
// properties

  int currentTab = 0;

List<File> _imageArray = new List<File>();

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageStorage(
        child:  Homepage_1(imageArray: _imageArray),
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 80, height: 80),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong, size: 39),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Camera(
                setData: (File file) {
                  _imageArray.add(file);
                  print("_imageArray--    " + _imageArray.length.toString());
                  setState(() {});
                }),
            ));
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shape: CircleBorder(), primary: Color(0xff33333D)),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 150,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(
                              () {
                            // currentScreen = Homepage_1();
                            // currentTab = 0;
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ImageIcon(
                              AssetImage("assets/Home_Selected.png"),
                              color: currentTab == 0
                                  ? Color(0xff33333D)
                                  : Color(0xffC6CBD1),
                            ),
                          ]),
                    )
                  ]),
                  Row(children: <Widget>[
                    MaterialButton(
                      minWidth: 150,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(
                              () {
                            // currentScreen = Settings();
                            // currentTab = 1;
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ImageIcon(
                              AssetImage("assets/Settings.png"),
                              color: currentTab == 1
                                  ? Color(0xff33333D)
                                  : Color(0xffC6CBD1),
                            ),
                          ]),
                    )
                  ])
                ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

then camera file.

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Camera extends StatefulWidget {
  Function setData;
  Camera({Key key,this.setData}):super(key: key);

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<Camera> {
  CameraController controller;
  List cameras;
  int selectedCameraIndex;
  String imgPath;
  var image;

  Future _openGallery() async {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if(widget.setData!=null) {
        widget.setData(image);
      }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    availableCameras().then((availableCameras) {
      cameras = availableCameras;

      if (cameras.length > 0) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCameraIndex = 0;
        });
        _initCameraController(cameras[selectedCameraIndex]).then((void v) {});
      } else {
        print('No camera available');
      }
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error :${err.code}Error message : ${err.message}');
    });
  }

  Future _initCameraController(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (controller != null) {
      await controller.dispose();
    }
    controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

    controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }

      if (controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  height: 120,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _cameraToggleRowWidget(),
                      _cameraControlWidget(context),
                      Spacer()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display Camera preview.
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text(
        'Loading',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        ),
      );
    }

    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
      child: CameraPreview(controller),
    );
  }

  /// Display the control bar with buttons to take pictures
  Widget _cameraControlWidget(context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.camera,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                // getImage();
                _openGallery();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
  Widget _cameraToggleRowWidget() {
    if (cameras == null || cameras.isEmpty) {
      return Spacer();
    }
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

    return Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: FlatButton.icon(
          onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
          icon: Icon(
            _getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection),
            color: Colors.white,
            size: 24,
          ),
          label: Text(
            '${lensDirection.toString().substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.') + 1).toUpperCase()}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
    switch (direction) {
      case CameraLensDirection.back:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera;
      case CameraLensDirection.front:
        return CupertinoIcons.switch_camera_solid;
      case CameraLensDirection.external:
        return Icons.camera;
      default:
        return Icons.device_unknown;
    }
  }

  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error:${e.code}\nError message : ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);
  }


  void _onSwitchCamera() {
    selectedCameraIndex =
    selectedCameraIndex < cameras.length - 1 ? selectedCameraIndex + 1 : 0;
    CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIndex];
    _initCameraController(selectedCamera);
  }
}
```

Homepage_1 to display images.

```
 import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage_1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<File> imageArray;
  Homepage_1({Key key, this.imageArray}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Homepage_1State createState() => _Homepage_1State();
}

class _Homepage_1State extends State<Homepage_1> {
  var image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 40, right: 0, bottom: 0),
            child:
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
              Text(
                'Title',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 60,
                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  margin:
                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 70, bottom: 0),
                  child: widget.imageArray.isEmpty
                      ? Column(children: [
                          Text(
                            'Yikes! You have no photos',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 19,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Click the circular button below.',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ])
                      :
                  GridView.count(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          children:
                              List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                            return Container(
                                child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index]));
                          })))
            ]),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue because i spent lot time for it. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending it back to the homepage the right way. There is no imgPath variable in your Homepage_1 Widget, you must add it before:

```
class Homepage_1 extends StatefulWidget {

   //specify a FINAL variable
   final imgPath;
   
   //this is the constructor which allows you to send it
   const Homepage_1({this.imgPath});
   
   @override
   _Homepage_1State createState() => _Homepage_1State();

}
```

Now you can access the imgPath variable in your State class like this:

```
this.widget.imgPath
```

Push to Homescreen_1 like so:

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Homepage_1(
                  imgPath: path,
                )),
```

Comment: Just tried, and still, nothing renders to the homepage_1. I edited the code to include your edits... could you please take another look? At a loss here...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are still testing the camera library and try to pass the image from class `Camera` to class `Homepage_1`, so I just focus on the data passing part. There are some small mistakes you made:

**class Camera**

1. I assume you want to use `_onCapturePressed` (not `_openGallery`) to send the image path to the home page. The actual file path is returned from takePicture()

   ```
   final xFile = await controller.takePicture();
   ...
   Navigator.push(
      ...
      imgPath: xFile.path,
   ...
   ```

**class Homepage_1**

2. You use `imageArray` to build the grid but not adding any file/path to it.

   ```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     if (widget.imgPath != null) {
       imageArray.add(File(widget.imgPath));
     }

     ...
       child: GridView.count(
         crossAxisCount: 2,
         children: List.generate(
           imageArray.length,
           (index) {
             var img = imageArray[index];
             return Container(child: Image.file(img));
           },
         ),
       ),
   ```

Then it should work now.

Notice:

- Library `ImagePicker` is open the native camera/gallery on phone and Library `Camera` is to customize your camera inside your app, which is not suggested to use them at the same time.
- Because the **class Camera** & **class Homepage_1** are not on the same level of screens (You use `Navigator.push` to stack the Camera screen over Homepage_1). The best way to update Homepage_1 is to use `Navigator.pop` in the Camera and bring the image path back to Homepage_1. (You can check the reference [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data#yep-button))